# Drawing a straight line iOS

Tags: ios, touch, line

I am drawing a straight line using this code (on user touch obviously) and I need to display the straight line from the start point until where the user is holding the touch (not ended the touch) like a rubber band from the start point, following the finger wherever it moves. I might have overlooked something I need to modify to create the necessary effect. Any idea?

NOTE : I am inside a View Controller.

```
- (void) drawLine:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender
{

    NSLog(@"Sender : %@", sender);
    CGPoint currentPoint;

    //CGAffineTransformMakeScale(lastScale, lastScale);
    if([(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan ||                                       [(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
    {
        currentPoint = [(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender locationInView:imgView];

        previousPoint = currentPoint;
    }

    if([(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) 
    { 
        touchedPoint = [(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender locationInView:imgView]; 
        [imgView setNeedsDisplay]; 
    }

    if([(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {
        currentPoint = [(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender locationInView:imgView];
        imgView.image =  [self drawLineFromPoint:previousPoint toPoint:currentPoint   image:imgView.image];

        previousPoint = currentPoint;

    }

}
```

This is the [drawline frompoint: topoint:] method

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imgView.frame.size);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();       
CGContextSaveGState(context);

CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0.0, imgView.frame.size.height);
CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);

CGContextSetShouldAntialias(context, YES);
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 1.0f);
CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 1.0);

CGContextMoveToPoint(context, fromPoint.x, fromPoint.y);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, toPoint.x, toPoint.y);
CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathStroke); 

CGContextRestoreGState(context);

NSLog(@"frompoint.x : %f, frompoint.y : %f",fromPoint.x, fromPoint.y );
NSLog(@"topoint.x : %f, topoint.y : %f", toPoint.x, toPoint.y);

UIImage *ret = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: what happens if you try with that code? What does your drawLineFromPoint:toPoint method do?

Comment: You overlooked the most important part...actually doing something when the gesture moves.  Right now you only have logic for when the touch starts and when it ends.

Comment: I have tried setNeedsDisplay in the Touches Moved part. No result.

Comment: Tried this.                                     `if([(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
    {
        touchedPoint = [(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender locationInView:imgView];
        [imgView setNeedsDisplay];
    }`

Comment: edited question to add code for `drawline frompoint: topoint:`

Comment: Is your gesture recognizer working fine? Does your log print the correct x/y value from start, to end point ? If not, I would suggest subclassing the UIView and overriding the touches began and touches ended events to get the x/y start/end coordinates

Comment: This is a UIImageView. Is there something I need to do differently?

Comment: The line is ending up somewhere unintended though. Probably expected behavior.

Comment: The from point, to Point and the touches began point and the touches ended point are the same when I checked.

Comment: Thanks, found the solution. Will be allowed to mark it as answer only tomorrow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[DrawingApp](https://github.com/zelox991/DrawingApp) This is a sample project I found which does what was desired.

Another approach is, as Lefteris suggested in the comment, inside UIView, override touches began, moved and ended. And use drawRect to draw the line. The line will drag to wherever your current touch is.