# Draw a line objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, draw, gesture

I'm a beginner of objective C, I was trying to make a program with a Paint style, I'm stack on drawing a line with the pan gesture. I can make the gesture but the problem is that I can't draw behind where i passed with the mouse, every time it reloads the point where I am deleting the one before. Help! Thank you a lot!
This is the code in that section:

```
-(void)pan: (UIPanGestureRecognizer*)panGesture
{
    if(panGesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {    
        _panLocation = [panGesture locationInView:self];
    }
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [self drawLine:context];
}

-(void)drawLine:(CGContextRef)context {    
    if (self.tag == 0) {
        [[UIColor blackColor] setFill];
        UIGraphicsPushContext(context);
        CGContextBeginPath(context);
        CGContextAddArc(context, _panLocation.x, _panLocation.y, 4, 0, 2*M_PI, YES);
        CGContextSetAlpha(context, 1);
        CGContextFillPath(context);
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12527482/drawing-a-straight-line-ios

Comment: Check it. 1. http://www.ios-developer.net/iphone-ipad-programmer/development/window-uiviewcontroller-etc/graphics/drawing-graphics-on-a-view  2. http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/smooth-freehand-drawing-on-ios--mobile-13164

Comment: monikanta thanks so much, that is the best link you could find!
WorldOfWarcraft i like your name and thank you, i found better links but thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it will help

Refer [draw line with gesture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6436990/draw-line-with-gesture) link where drawing is done with UIPanGestureRecognizer.

Or else you can do this using touch delegate methods
for that follow the link

[draw line by touch](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1998968&seqNum=8)

Comment: sorry, i'm new here, i didn't see that